# pass value from view to controller in MVC throws error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the below code which will accept the values from the user and these values needs to be transfer to the controller. I can use action link ,but I would like to know how request.input variable works here.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginResult", "Dashboard",  FormMethod.Post))
{

 @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.username)
```

In controller :

```
 public ActionResult LoginResult()
    {
        string strName = Request["username"].ToString();         
        return View();
    }
```

and model

```
 public class Employee
    {

            public string username { get; set; }
            public string age { get; set; }

    }
```

but getting error

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   MvcApplication5.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

Comment: These values are posted back to the controller once you submit the form. Incase of having an action link, you are going to submit the form on the click or post the data via Ajax.

Comment: Avoid using `Request` in your controller. Try to stick to letting the framework do it's work for you, letting the model binder bind to parameters etc.

Comment: [Just about all your code is not done in the MVC Framework/Style](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started)... I highly recommend you actually make Models (MVC = Model View Controller), use EditorFor etc.  Otherwise there is really no point in using MVC, you might as well use [WebPages](https://www.asp.net/web-pages).

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you would handle this

```
<body>
    <h2>Dashboard</h2>
    <form method="post" action="" >
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="textname" name="txtname" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="textpassword" name="textpassword" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" id="btnclickhere" name="btnclickhere" value="ClickHere" />
                </td>
            </tr>
           <tr><td>**<input type="submit" value="Save" />**</td></tr>
        </tbody>           
    </table>
     </form>
```

Or else, you will have an link that looks something like below

```
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="doLogin()" >Login</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function doLogin(){
var postData = {
       username = $("#textname").val(),
       password = $("#textpassword").val
};
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/account/logon',
  data: JSON.stringify(postData),
  success: function(result){
},
  contentType:"application/json",
  dataType: "json"
});
}
</script>
```

I would like to suggest to you that you better post the form and not use the values in an ajax one. Also, put the page on a HTTPS site for better safety.

Hope this Helps

Comment: Thanks saravanan. I have updated the code as shown in your answer but still im getting the same error.I have updated the code in my question. Could you please tell me where it gone wrong?